MockMvc pefrorm method doesnt actually perform my http request
So I am busy with small project for my school and I am writing the test class for my movie controller class (using Spring Data JPA). All endpoints from my controller class are working fine, but when I write a test for my PATCH request with MockMvc I find no result matching my adjusted record. I get status 200 but when trying to assert the record it finds none.
Patch request code from controller class:
    @PatchMapping("{id}/ranking")
    void changeRanking(@PathVariable long id, @RequestBody @NotNull @Min(0) @Max(10) BigDecimal ranking) {
        movieService.changeRanking(id, ranking);
    }

Service class code from changeRanking method:
    @Transactional
    void changeRanking(long id, BigDecimal ranking) {
        movieRepository.findAndLockById(id)
                .orElseThrow(MovieNietGevondenException::new)
                .setRanking(ranking);
    }

Code for my test:
    @Test
    void changeRankingAdjustsAMovieRanking() throws Exception {
        long id = idTestMovie();

        mockMvc.perform(patch("/movies/{id}/ranking", id)
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .content("7"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
        assertThat(JdbcTestUtils.countRowsInTableWhere(jdbcClient, MOVIES_TABLE, "ranking = 7 and name like 'testMovie' and id = " + id)).isOne();
    }

I tried to assert the data from existing record and it passes the test so assertion works fine. When I send HTTP request with intelliJ, it does the changes in database. When i test my endpoint with wrong data i also get the desired status. I tried to change the way of passing Big Decimal as a JSON but it doesnt work either. I have written already multiple test like that with basically the same data and types and never had such a problem. your text
